# I have a string declared as Global that functions as my password, but when I change the value of the string it doesn't run

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

Someone gave me a code, that he used with a global declared constant as a password set as "321123".
This with the objective of just changing the value there and not in every single line, but when I changed the value, the code just stops telling me:

> Incorrect password, Error 1004
>
> The password is incorrect

But the issue is that the user doesn't have to enter anything, now I'm done trying to find the mistake, and after all of this, the whole ribbon just blocks itself.

Here's the code:

```
1 Public Const myGenericPassword = "5"

2 Sub LockUnlockSheet(myLock As Boolean, mySheetName As String)
3     If myLock = True Then
4        Sheets(mySheetName).Protect userinterfaceonly:=True, Password:=myGenericPassword
5    Else
6        Sheets(mySheetName).Unprotect Password:=myGenericPassword
7    End If
8 End Sub
```

When debugging, the mistake is on line 6.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Where is the code that is calling this sub??

Comment: Was the sheet already unlocked when you changed the value of the const password? As the `unprotect` line will not work if you haven't used the same password to protect the sheet.

Comment: Is it possible that the sheet is still locked with the original password of "321123"?  If this is the case, you'll need to unlock it with that password first, before you re-lock it with your own password.

Comment: It was just that. Thanks @ElijahMoreau-Arnott

Comment: It was just that. Thanks @Greedo